# How to add specific configuration to a Spring Cloud OpenFeign client defined in a library?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I use a [library](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-rest-client-spring-boot) that defines some OpenFeign clients using spring-cloud-openfeign. I need to add an interceptor to these clients to add an authorization header without changing the library code.

So far I just defined the interceptor as a Spring bean and everything worked. But now I added another OpenFeign client that needs a different interceptor, which I defined using the `configuration` attribute of the `@FeignClient` annotation. My problem is that the new client now gets both interceptors.

I tried configuring the first interceptor using application properties instead, but the interceptor needs to get another bean injected, which seems to require defining it as a bean, which would add it to the second client again.

I also tried to find an equivalent to CDI's `@Typed` annotation so that the interceptor would only be found when looking for it's concrete class but not when looking for the `RequestInterceptor` interface, but couldn't find any.

Is there any way to add a configuration to an OpenFeign client defined in a library such that it does not affect any other clients?

Comment: if the library is doing `@FeignClient` as well, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a custom feign configuration.

```
@FeignClient(name = "stores", configuration = CustomConfiguration.class)
public interface StoreClient {
    //..
}
```

and your custom configuracion will call to your custom interceptor. You could implement some logic in your custom interceptor.

`if (request uri contains some pattern)  add some headers`

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work because the `@FeignClient` annotation is in the library I can't touch.
Of course I could use a global interceptor and check the request URI there, but that doesn't feel like a clean solution to me.